# I have a issue in ExtJS form: When select a radio button then on focus event not executed in all browsers

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a issue in ExtJS form. When select a radio button on my form then on focus event not executed in all browsers.
Like everything work almost fine in Firefox (Mac) but nothing works on Google Chrome (Mac).
I am not tested my ExtJS from in a PC only in Mac.
Sometimes in Firefox everything not work correctly on all browser loads.

Here is some source code about functions which not always work fine:

```
Radio1.on('focus', function(){

            //alert('test1');
            Ext.getCmp('combo1').enable();
            Ext.getCmp('combo2').disable();

            Ext.getCmp('option3').disable();
            Ext.getCmp('option4').disable();
            Ext.getCmp('option5').disable();
            Ext.getCmp('option6').disable();
            Ext.getCmp('option7').disable();
            Ext.getCmp('option8').disable();
            Ext.getCmp('option9').disable();
            Ext.getCmp('option10').disable();

        });

Radio2.on('focus', function(){

            //alert('test2');
            Ext.getCmp('combo1').disable();
            Ext.getCmp('combo2').enable();

            Ext.getCmp('option3').enable();
            Ext.getCmp('option4').enable();
            Ext.getCmp('option5').enable();
            Ext.getCmp('option6').enable();
            Ext.getCmp('option7').enable();
            Ext.getCmp('option8').enable();
            Ext.getCmp('option9').enable();
            Ext.getCmp('option10').enable();

        });
```

How to fix code? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your want to do that on *focus*? What are you trying to achieve? Isn't it when the radio is selected that you want to detect?

Comment: No, I just want to make a feature that disables/enables form items when I select between two radio buttons. It do not need happen in focus.